# XSLT document() function - for loop table doesn't work

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am currently working on a homework task that my teacher has given me.
I am to create a single XSL stylesheet that displays the data from different xml files.

I have created a XSL file called weather.xsl that displays the weather data from two xml files given by my teacher called IDN10031.xml and IDN11032.xml.

The two xml files look like this:

IDN10031.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="weather-1.xsl"?>
<product version="1.7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.bom.gov.au/schema/v1.7/product.xsd">
    <amoc>
        <source>
            <sender>Australian Government Bureau of Meteorology</sender>
            <region>New South Wales</region>
            <office>NSWRO</office>
            <copyright>http://www.bom.gov.au/other/copyright.shtml</copyright>
            <disclaimer>http://www.bom.gov.au/other/disclaimer.shtml</disclaimer>
        </source>
        <identifier>IDN10031</identifier>
        <issue-time-utc>2018-04-25T18:30:00Z</issue-time-utc>
        <issue-time-local tz="EST">2018-04-26T04:30:00+10:00</issue-time-local>
        <sent-time>2018-04-25T18:30:03Z</sent-time>
        <expiry-time>2018-05-05T18:30:00Z</expiry-time>
        <validity-bgn-time-local tz="EST">2018-04-26T04:30:02+10:00</validity-bgn-time-local>
        <validity-end-time-local tz="EST">2018-04-29T23:59:59+10:00</validity-end-time-local>
        <next-routine-issue-time-utc>2018-04-26T06:30:00Z</next-routine-issue-time-utc>
        <next-routine-issue-time-local tz="EST">2018-04-26T16:30:00+10:00</next-routine-issue-time-local>
        <status>O</status>
        <service>WSP</service>
        <sub-service>FST</sub-service>
        <product-type>F</product-type>
        <phase>NEW</phase>
    </amoc>
    <forecast>
        <area aac="NSW_FA001" description="New South Wales" type="region">
            <forecast-period start-time-local="2018-04-26T04:30:02+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-26T04:30:02+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T18:30:02Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-25T18:30:02Z">
                <text type="synoptic_situation">
                    <p>A low pressure trough off the New South Wales north coast is weakening as a high pressure system south of the Bight moves very slowly east extending a ridge along the coast. The high is expected to move over the southern Tasman by Wednesday maintaining the ridge to the north.</p>
                </text>
                <text type="warning_summary_footer">Details of warnings are available on the Bureau's website www.bom.gov.au, by telephone 1300-659-218* or through some TV and radio broadcasts.</text>
                <text type="product_footer">* Calls to 1300 numbers cost around 27.5c incl. GST, higher from mobiles or public phones.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T19:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="fire_danger">Very High: Northwestern fire area.</text>
                <text type="forecast">Medium chance of showers along the northern half of the coast with the risk of thunderstorms. The chance of afternoon thunderstorms in the northern inland. Early fog in the east. Partly cloudy elsewhere. Daytime temperatures close to average. Winds south to southwesterly, freshening along the coast and about the central west slopes.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">A shower or two in the east, more likely about the north coast. The chance of a thunderstorm in the far northeast. Early frost patches about the southern ranges. Fine and mostly sunny in the west. Daytime temperatures below average, especially in the southeast. South to southeasterly winds, freshening about the northeast and along the coast.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Showers in the east, more likely about the central and northern coastal fringe. Fine and mostly sunny elsewhere. Early frost patches about the southern ranges. Daytime temperatures below average in the east and about average elsewhere. South to southeasterly winds, freshening about the north coast.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-29T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Showers in the east, more likely about the central and north coast. Fine and mostly sunny elsewhere. Early frost patches about the southern ranges. Daytime temperatures below average in the east, about average elsewhere. South to southeasterly winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
    </forecast>
</product>
```

IDN11032.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product version="1.7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.bom.gov.au/schema/v1.7/product.xsd">
    <amoc>
        <source>
            <sender>Australian Government Bureau of Meteorology</sender>
            <region>New South Wales</region>
            <office>NSWRO</office>
            <copyright>http://www.bom.gov.au/other/copyright.shtml</copyright>
            <disclaimer>http://www.bom.gov.au/other/disclaimer.shtml</disclaimer>
        </source>
        <identifier>IDN11032</identifier>
        <issue-time-utc>2018-04-25T23:51:29Z</issue-time-utc>
        <issue-time-local tz="EST">2018-04-26T09:51:29+10:00</issue-time-local>
        <sent-time>2018-04-25T23:51:29Z</sent-time>
        <expiry-time>2018-04-26T23:51:29Z</expiry-time>
        <validity-bgn-time-local tz="EST">2018-04-26T00:00:00+10:00</validity-bgn-time-local>
        <validity-end-time-local tz="EST">2018-04-29T23:59:59+10:00</validity-end-time-local>
        <next-routine-issue-time-utc>2018-04-26T06:30:00Z</next-routine-issue-time-utc>
        <next-routine-issue-time-local tz="EST">2018-04-26T16:30:00+10:00</next-routine-issue-time-local>
        <status>O</status>
        <service>WSP</service>
        <sub-service>FAA</sub-service>
        <product-type>F</product-type>
        <phase>UPD</phase>
    </amoc>
    <forecast>
        <area aac="NSW_FA001" description="New South Wales" type="region">
            <forecast-period start-time-local="2018-04-26T09:51:28+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-26T09:51:28+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T23:51:28Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-25T23:51:28Z">
                <text type="warning_summary_footer">Details of warnings are available on the Bureau's website www.bom.gov.au, by telephone 1300-659-218* or through some TV and radio broadcasts.</text>
                <text type="synoptic_situation">
                    <p>A low pressure trough off the New South Wales north coast is weakening as a high pressure system south of the Bight moves very slowly east extending a ridge along the coast. The high is expected to move over the southern Tasman by Wednesday maintaining the ridge to the north.</p>
                </text>
                <text type="product_footer">* Calls to 1300 numbers cost around 27.5c incl. GST, higher from mobiles or public phones.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_PW010" description="Snowy Mountains" type="public-district" parent-aac="NSW_FA001">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2018-04-26T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="snow_elevation_1">1000</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_1">0%</element>
                <element type="snow_elevation_2">1400</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_2">0%</element>
                <element type="snow_elevation_3">1800</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_3">0%</element>
                <text type="forecast">Mostly sunny. Winds south to southwesterly 15 to 25 km/h becoming light in the evening then becoming south to southwesterly 15 to 20 km/h in the late evening.</text>
                <text type="uv_alert">Sun protection 10:00am to 1:50pm, UV Index predicted to reach 4 [Moderate]</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="snow_elevation_1">1000</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_1">0%</element>
                <element type="snow_elevation_2">1400</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_2">0%</element>
                <element type="snow_elevation_3">1800</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_3">Below 5%</element>
                <text type="forecast">Cloudy. Slight (20%) chance of a shower near the Victorian border. Winds south to southwesterly 15 to 20 km/h tending south to southeasterly in the middle of the day then becoming light in the late afternoon.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="snow_elevation_1">1000</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_1">0%</element>
                <element type="snow_elevation_2">1400</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_2">0%</element>
                <element type="snow_elevation_3">1800</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_3">0%</element>
                <text type="forecast">Partly cloudy. The chance of patchy early morning frost. Light winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-29T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="snow_elevation_1">1000</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_1">0%</element>
                <element type="snow_elevation_2">1400</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_2">0%</element>
                <element type="snow_elevation_3">1800</element>
                <element type="probability_of_snow_at_elevation_3">0%</element>
                <text type="forecast">Partly cloudy. Slight (20%) chance of a shower in the east. Light winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_PT115" description="Perisher Valley" type="location" parent-aac="NSW_PW010">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T19:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">11</element>
                <text type="precis">Mostly sunny.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">8</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">-3</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">10</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">-2</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-29T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">10</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">-3</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_PT036" description="Cooma" type="location" parent-aac="NSW_PW010">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T19:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">21</element>
                <text type="precis">Mostly sunny.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">4</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">16</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">1</element>
                <text type="precis">Cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">18</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">1</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-29T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">4</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">18</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">1</element>
                <text type="precis">Cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_PT024" description="Cabramurra" type="location" parent-aac="NSW_PW010">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T19:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">1</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">14</element>
                <text type="precis">Sunny.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">11</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">4</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">12</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">4</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-29T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">13</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">4</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_PT044" description="Thredbo Top Station" type="location" parent-aac="NSW_PW010">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T19:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">1</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">10</element>
                <text type="precis">Sunny.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">10</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">6</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">-1</element>
                <text type="precis">Early fog.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">8</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">0</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-29T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">8</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">-1</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_PT217" description="Jindabyne" type="location" parent-aac="NSW_PW010">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T19:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">17</element>
                <text type="precis">Mostly sunny.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">4</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">12</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">3</element>
                <text type="precis">Cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">15</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">4</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-29T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">15</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">3</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
    </forecast>
</product>
```

I am required to use IDN10031.xml as my main document and then use the XSLT `document()` function to get the weather data from IDN11032.xml

Here is what my XSL stylesheet looks like right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="product">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>State Weather</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="weather.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>NSW and ACT Weather</h3>
                <p>Forecast for the rest of <xsl:value-of select="forecast/area/forecast-period/@start-time-local"/></p>
                <p><xsl:value-of select="forecast/area/forecast-period[2]/text[2]"/></p>
                <br/>
            <h3>Snowy Mountains District Weather</h3>
                <xsl:for-each select="document('IDN11032.xml')/product/forecast/area[@aac = 'NSW_PW010']/forecast-period[position() &lt; 4]">
                    <xsl:variable name="current_index" select="@index"/>
                    <p>Forecast for <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date(substring(current()/@start-time-local,1,10)), '[FNn] [D1] [MNn]')"/></p>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="text[@type = 'forecast']"/></p>
                        <table>
                            <xsl:sort select="parent::node()/@description"/>
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="parent::node()/description"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="text[@type = 'precis']"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="element[@type = 'air_temperature_minimum']"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="element[@type = 'air_temperature_maximum']"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Before I added the data for 'Snowy Mountains District Weather' it was working fine. So i think my problem started when implemented the `document()` function and the table.

This is the result I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Ever since I implemented the `document()` function along with the table my stylesheet was not displaying anything.

Can anyone help me please...
It would be most appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So how do run the stylesheet, which tool do you use to "display" the result?

Comment: The whole markup is odd, you have `tr` and `th/td` elements outside of any `table` and then you have a `table` containing an `xsl:sort`, which doesn't make sense and is not allowed.

Comment: I use a http python server to display and test @MartinHonnen

Comment: I want to sort the table in alphabetical order, oh and thank you for pointing out the tr and th/td outside the table that was a miss type @MartinHonnen

Comment: Try to use an environment that displays any errors the used XSLT processor gives, if you simply try to look at the resulting HTML you have a hard time debugging any XSLT. In general your code uses XSLT/XPath 2 features like `format-date` or `xs:date` (and the latter without declaring the namespace), so I doubt that code did anything before using the `document` function, it has errors more fundamental. Furthermore to use XSLT 2 you need an XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 9, most Python implementations use an XSLT 1 processor like libxslt.